# Compare Comparable number of different types to zero

Tags: java, generics, numbers

I have such code:

```
    BigDecimal n1= BigDecimal.TEN;
    Long n2= 15L;

    nullOrNonPositive(n1);
    nullOrNonPositive(n2);
```

And method code:

```
    private boolean nullOrNonPositive(Comparable value) {
        return isNull(value) || value.compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) <= 0;
    }
```

I do get an `Exception` that `Long` cannot be compared to `BigDecimal`, which is pretty obvious. Is there a way to make the method generic and compare `Comparable`, which will always be a number (but different class), to zero?

Comment: Why do you want to compare *any* Comparable to a BigDecimal? They are not the same type.

Comment: Why not use `Number` instead of `Comparable` and cast to double and check < 0?

Answer (score 1):

I would take a parameter that denotes the `zero` value for the type represented by the Comparator and let the caller pass it.

```
private static <T> boolean nullOrNonPositive(Comparable<T> value, T zero) {
    return isNull(value) || value.compareTo(zero) <= 0;
}
```

Call it as

```
nullOrNonPositive(n1, BigDecimal.ZERO); //false
nullOrNonPositive(n2, 0L); //false

nullOrNonPositive(-1L, 0L); //true
nullOrNonPositive(2, 0)); //true

nullOrNonPositive("1", "0"); //false
nullOrNonPositive("0", "0"); //true
```

If the set of possible types (`T`) is limited, you can stores the zero values in a map.

Answer (score 1):

Building upon user7's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57331117/8929501), if you don't want to have to pass the zero value, you can add methods that call the main function. This frees the caller from having to know what the `zero` value is for each type.

```
private static <T> boolean nullOrNonPositive(Comparable<T> value, T zero) {
  return isNull(value) || value.compareTo(zero) <= 0;    
}

private boolean nullOrNonPositive(BigDecimal value) {
  return nullOrNonPositive(value, BigDecimal.ZERO)
}

private boolean nullOrNonPositive(Long value) {
  return nullOrNonPositive(value, 0L);
}
```

Comment: Never mind I thought you were calling your top method first, read it wrong direction.

Comment: @Nexevis It frees the caller from having to know what the `zero` is for each type. I'm not sure what you mean by "overload all of them and pass it alone"

Comment: @Beteaux I was talking about exactly what you did, I just read it incorrectly the first time.  Was my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Or if you don't want to define the 0 for each number, and you always use `nullOrNonPositive` for numbers, you could do:

```
private boolean nullOrNonPositive(Number value) {
    return isNull(value) || new BigDecimal(value.toString()).signum() <= 0;
}
```